# How to trap a websocket 503 max connections in javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket

My websocket code works fine as long as I don't exceed my number of connections.  I want to trap when the 503 error occurs.  Console output that shows up is as follows:

> SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 503, Number of active WebSocket requests has reached the maximum concurrent WebSocket requests allowed.

WebSocket.OnError handler doesn't surface out the full detail.  How can I get the detail level as shown in the console output above?  Some kind of document collection or, well, I don't know really.

Full code here.  Socket server is alive and INTENTIONALLY limited to 4 connections as of 12/6.  Will chop it down later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/base.css" />
<title>Yielding Loop</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = 0;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on = 0;
    var m_connection = null;
    var m_socket_address = "ws://edgeplay.azurewebsites.net/ws";

    function timedCount()
    {
        echoTest();
        document.getElementById( "txt" ).value = c;
        outmsg( "tick=" + c );
        c = c + 1;
        t = setTimeout( function () { timedCount() }, 3000 );
    }

    function startCount()
    {
        if ( !timer_is_on )
        {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            timedCount();
        }
    }

    function stopCount()
    {
        clearTimeout( t );
        timer_is_on = 0;
    }

    function SocketInit()
    {
        try
        {
            if ( "WebSocket" in window )
            {
                outmsg( "WebSocket supported, gtg." );
            }
            else
            {
                outmsg( "WebSocket NOT SUPPORTED, bailing out" );
                return 0;
            }

            outmsg( "connecting to " + m_socket_address );

            try
            {
                m_connection = new WebSocket( m_socket_address );
            }
            catch ( err )
            {
                outmsg( "error creating new socket - " + err );
                outmsg( "error.name:" + err.name );
                outmsg( "error.message:" + err.message );
            }

            m_connection.onopen = function ( openEvent )
            {
                outmsg( "WebSocket.OnOpen - GTG: " + m_socket_address );
            };

            m_connection.onmessage = function ( messageEvent )
            {
                outmsg( 'WebSocket.onmessage - Server Reply:: ' + messageEvent.data );
            };

            m_connection.onerror = function ( errorEvent )
            {
                outmsg( "WebSocket Status:: Error was reported." );
                outmsg( "WebSocket errorEvent: " + errorEvent );
                outmsg( "Stopping count" );
                var h1 = document.getElementById( "h1Main" );
                h1.style = "background-color:red;";
                stopCount();
            };

            m_connection.onclose = function ( closeEvent )
            {
                outmsg( "WebSocket Status:: Socket Closed" );
                outmsg( "closeEvent.code:" + closeEvent.code );
                outmsg( "closeEvent.data:" + closeEvent.data );
            };
        }
        catch ( exception )
        {
            outmsg( "exception: " + exception );
        }
    }

    var m_input = null;
    var m_querystring = null;
    function echoTest()
    {
        try
        {
            m_input = m_input == null ? document.getElementById( "textEcho" ) : m_input;
            m_connection.send( m_input.value + location.search );
        }
        catch ( err )
        {
            outmsg( "eating error " + err );
        }
    }


    var m_out = null;
    var outd = null;
    function outmsg( msg )
    {
        m_out = ( m_out == null ) ? document.getElementById( "divOutput" ) : m_out;
        outd = new Date();
        m_out.innerHTML = outd.toLocaleTimeString() + ": " + msg + "<br/>" + m_out.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="SocketInit();startCount();">
<h1 id="h1Main">Yielding Loop</h1>
<button onclick="SocketInit();startCount();">Init socket and start count</button>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="stopCount()">Stop count!</button>
<br/>
<span>text to echo: </span><input type="text" value="BLUE" id="textEcho"/>

<div id="divOutput" style="background-color:antiquewhite; border:3px; width:900px;">
    ready....
</div>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Errors raised when it fails:

debugged into the error raised.  not much goodness in there.  output lines below.  Reverse chrono.

```
1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.reason:
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.data:undefined
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.code:1006
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: WebSocket.onClose
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- Stopping count
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- errorEvent.type: error
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- errorEvent: [object Event]
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: WebSocket.onerror
```

Comment: What exactly does `onerror` show you when a 503 occurs?

Comment: debugged into the error raised.  not much goodness in there.  output lines below.  Reverse chrono.  Placing into Q so we get better formatting.

1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.reason:
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.data:undefined
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- closeEvent.code:1006
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: WebSocket.onClose
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- Stopping count
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- errorEvent.type: error
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: --- errorEvent: [object Event]
‎1‎:‎04‎:‎59‎ ‎PM: WebSocket.onerror

Comment: What's in `errorEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you will only ever get a 1006 onclose for security reasons.  Not leaving my happy but that is the way the RFC is written.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network

> User agents must not convey any failure information to scripts in a
>   way that would allow a script to distinguish the following situations:
>   A server whose host name could not be resolved.  A server to which
>   packets could not successfully be routed.  A server that refused the
>   connection on the specified port.  A server that failed to correctly
>   perform a TLS handshake (e.g., the server certificate can't be
>   verified).  A server that did not complete the opening handshake (e.g.
>   because it was not a WebSocket server).  A WebSocket server that sent
>   a correct opening handshake, but that specified options that caused
>   the client to drop the connection (e.g. the server specified a
>   subprotocol that the client did not offer).  A WebSocket server that
>   abruptly closed the connection after successfully completing the
>   opening handshake.  In all of these cases, the the WebSocket
>   connection close code would be 1006, as required by the WebSocket
>   Protocol specification. [WSP]